# How to abort/kill a procedure in HBase

Tags: hbase

I got 2 stuck hbase procedures when I was trying to create a new table. I think maybe something wrong happened on the region server on that time.

Now I find a parent procedure marked as "WAITING" and its child procedure marked as "WAITING_TIMEOUT".

I want to abort/kill these 2 procedures, but I don't know how to do it and seems that hbase shell's "kill" operation doesn't support on procedures.

My hbase version is 2.0.2 and running on yarn.

I have tried to restart hbase, but the procedures are still there and remain stuck.

**Parent procedure**:

```
id:
54206

parent:
Empty, no parent

state: 
WAITING

type:
ServerCrashProcedure server=slave.server.com,16020,1558012223746, splitWal=true, meta=false
```

**Child procedure**:

```
id:
54266

parent:
54206

state:
WAITING_TIMEOUT

type:
AssignProcedure table=my_namespace:my_table, region=18b04016f7b5619c9fbd6dfcdf72e9d4
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue when running clone_snapshot command.
You can use list_procedures to get running procs and use abort_procedure command in hbase shell.
But in our version of hbase , list_procedures was going into OOM and abort_procedure was not available.
So I stopped all hbase services , deleted the files in /hbase/MasterProcWALs/
directory and started hbase.That has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question by accident and I'm going to post the solution, because HBase 2.x is still a current stable version.

**Short intro**

Starting with HBase2 there is a separate tool called "HBase Operator Tools" which is your best friend (and the only option in many cases) while dealing with any serious HBase cluster problems. It can be downloaded from Apache HBase site.

My understanding is, that they decided to "take out" this tool out of HBase distribution in order to let us (users/admins) use the latest admin tools without needing to upgrade the HBase version itself.

**How to install and use the HBCK2**

1. Download the latest HBase Operator Tools binary (tar.gz file) from https://hbase.apache.org/downloads.html (section HBase Operator Tools)
2. Extract it on a node of the cluster (I have it on HBase master server), preferably on **hbase** or other HBase admin user. After extracting you will find a directory called **hbase-operator-tools-1.1.0/hbase-hbck2** with a bunch of jars inside (1.1.0 is a latest version at the time I'm writing this answer)
3. `kinit` if Kerberos is enabled
4. run `hbase hbck -j hbase-operator-tools-1.1.0/hbase-hbck2/hbase-hbck2-1.1.0.jar` and you will see a bunch of pretty well explained options available like: `addFsRegionsMissingInMeta`, `assigns`, `setRegionState`, `fixMeta` and more

**It is importat to realize, that this tool can also operate on Zookeeper level so it will help you even if HBase itself cannot start, for example HBase Master startup is stuck because of some region in transition**

**Finally to the solution**

When you run
`hbase hbck -j hbase-operator-tools-1.1.0/hbase-hbck2/hbase-hbck2-1.1.0.jar --help`
there will be an option `bypass`, which is exactly what you need:

```
bypass [OPTIONS] < PID >...
  Options:
    -o,--override   override if procedure is running/stuck
    -r,--recursive  bypass parent and its children. SLOW! EXPENSIVE!
    -w,--lockWait   milliseconds to wait before giving up; default=1    
 Pass one (or more) procedure 'pid's to skip to procedure finish.  Parent of bypassed procedure will also be skipped to the finish.  Entities will be left in an inconsistent state and will require manual fixup. May need Master restart to clear locks still held.  Bypass fails if procedure has children.  Add 'recursive' if all you have is a parent pid to finish parent and children. This is SLOW, and dangerous so use selectively. Does not always work.
```

So finally:

```
hbase hbck -j hbase-operator-tools-1.1.0/hbase-hbck2/hbase-hbck2-1.1.0.jar bypass -o -r PROCEDURE_PID
```

The procedure along with it's parents should be killed.